# Microservices: Https endpoints can only be configured using KestrelServerOptions.Listen

Tags: https, microservices, kestrel

I am working on IdentityServer in Microservice. I am having issued with exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'HTTPS endpoints can only be configured using KestrelServerOptions.Listen().'

I placed UseKestrel() inside the BuildWebHost in Program.cs file. What other thing do I need to configure. I can see a Certificate folder under eShopOnContainer project. How do I generate this files.

This is the identity server docker.compose config:

```
    services:
  identitywithdocker:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44301
    ports:
      - "64636:80"
      - "44301:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```